# What is the longest walkable section of the Great Wall of China?

Tags: china, factoids, walking, great-wall-of-china

Which part of the Great Wall of China is the longest continuous segment that you can walk (and/or climb) on (that is accessible and still stands as a wall) without disobeying no go signs?

Comment: Note sure if only related or a duplicate: [How far I can go before I reach a tourist-nogo zone from Badaling, the great wall of China?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72682/32134), please also have a look to the answers! That being said, please define "continuous segment that you can walk on". Are you ready [to climb](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64263/32134)?

Comment: The no-go signs are not 100% respected so you might want to clarify whether you include breaking the rules.

Comment: @mts That starts at a specific place, so, related, but not duplicate, I think? An answer with and without steps would be interesting, but I suspect answering including "climb" as part of "walk" is probably much simpler.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany updated question

Comment: +1 as the question is much clearer now, but I'd still like some clarification: are you considering only "official sections" or any section that is accessible and still stands as a wall? E.g. since the linked Jiankou section is nothing official, there are no "no-go" signs and you could walk and climb for days!

Comment: Do you mind if it's a "wild wall"? There are more than one wall and sections that are in very poor shape are known as the "wild wall", though I'm not sure if there's any exact definition for that. A section I walked along near Zhangjiakou was like a very long mound and not high at all. Not saying that the longest section will be in better or worse shape because I don't know. But it might not resemble in the slightest what you imagine the Great Wall to look like. [Somebody else's photo](http://thehutong.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/overlooking-zhangjiakou.jpg)

Comment: @hippietrail If I'd like the answer with and without wild walls, should I ask that as a separate question?

Comment: @movieglass in my personal opinion your question is great as it is, but it might take a while for a good answer to come around. I would leave it as is for now. Do you intend to hike said section? You might want to contact and ask [this guy who walked the whole wall](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/72684/32134). You are probably in for a multiple-days trip at least.

Comment: @movieglass: Another point is, longest in kilometres, or longest in hours? Some sections may be extremely difficult. The wall was built through all kinds of incredible terrain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have walked through Simatai and Badaling segments of Great Wall. Badaling segment is longer (around 7 miles). Simatai is twice shorter (3.5 miles) but way more strenuous, so if you're looking for more exercise and not merely longer walk, Simatai is more difficult. It is also much less crowded, and scenery is better; Badaling is over-restored in my opinion. However Badaling is way more accessible with public transport (and thus more crowded).

Note that with both of them you enter the wall at its one side, then walk to the other side, **hit the dead end and then walk all the way back**.You can only save a part of it by taking the cable car down, but you still need to get back to the station which is roughly to the middle of the wall. So the distance you walk doubles; keep that in mind when plan your walk.

Comment: That's a starting point but I am pretty sure there's plenty of wild sections of the wall that allow much longer hikes.

Comment: The OP stated "without disobeying no go signs"; the remaining pieces accessible from those spots all have no-go signs, often with a security officer nearby to enforce it. Other segments of the Wall are not open for tourism either.

Comment: not open for tourism does not equate to absence of no-go signs. The jiankou section mentioned is an inofficial spot and as such has no no-go signs and the same holds for many other sections. in comments the OP seemed to welcome such spots.

Comment: He asked for the section to be walkable ("you can walk"). Do you know if it is walkable? I only walked Simatai and Badaling, which indeed are.